# What does adduser do that useradd doesn't?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, users, useradd

In addition to the more widespread `useradd`, Debian based systems also contain an additional `adduser` command which provides a higher level interface for adding users and some related tasks. There are various questions/answers on other SE sites which detail the basic differences between these commands, for example:

- ServerFault - [What's the difference between 'useradd' and 'adduser'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218993/whats-the-difference-between-useradd-and-adduser)
- Superuser - [What's the difference between “adduser” and “useradd”?](https://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)
- Ask Ubuntu - [What is the difference between adduser and useradd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)

Most of the answers essentially say that `adduser` provides nicer interface for adding users interactively, but don't give much detail on what happens when `adduser` is run that doesn't compared to `useradd`. So:

1. What does `adduser` do that `useradd` doesn't?
2. What commands do I need to use to produce equivalent results?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

First off, the respective man page snippets highlight the differences between the two commands and give some indication of what is going on. For `adduser`:

> adduser  and  addgroup add users and groups to the system according to command line options and configuration information in /etc/adduser.conf.  They are friendlier front ends to
> the low level tools like useradd, groupadd and usermod programs, by default choosing Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home directory with skeletal configuration, running a custom script, and other features.

Then for `useradd`:

> useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

Further investigation of `adduser` reveals that it is a perl script providing a high level interface to, and thus offering some of the functionality of, the following commands:

- `useradd`
- `groupadd`
- `passwd` - used to add/change users passwords.
- `gpasswd` - used to add/change group passwords.
- `usermod` - used to change various user associated parameters.
- `chfn` - used to add/change additional information held on a user.
- `chage` - used to change password expiry information.
- `edquota` - used to change disk usage quotas.

A basic run of the `adduser` command is as follows:

```
adduser username
```

This simple command will do a number of things:

1. Create the user named `username`.
2. Create the user's home directory (default is `/home/username` and copy the files from `/etc/skel` into it.
3. Create a group with the same name as the user and place the user in it.
4. Prompt for a password for the user.
5. Prompt for additional information on the user.

The `useradd` program can most of accomplish most of this, however it does not do so by default and needs additional options. Some of the information requires more commands:

```
useradd -m -U username
passwd username
chfn username
```

Note that `adduser` ensures that created UIDs and GIDs conform with the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.2.2). Creating normal users with `useradd` seems to be ok, provided `UID_MIN`/`UID_MAX` in `/etc/login.defs` matches the Debian policy. What is a problem though is that Debian specifies a particular range for system user UIDs which only seems to be supported in `/etc/adduser.conf`, so naively adding a system user with `useradd` and not specifying a UID/GUID in the correct range leaves the potential for serious problems.

Another common use for `adduser` is to simplify the process of adding a user to a group. Here, the following command:

```
adduser username newgroup
```

is equivalent to the following `usermod` command:

```
usermod -a -G newgroup username
```

The main drawback from `usermod` in this case is that forgetting to pass the
append option (i.e.: `-a`) would end up removing the user from all groups
before adding them to "newgroup" (i.e.: `-G` alone means "replace with").

One downside to using `adduser` here though is that you can only specify one group at a time.

Comment: This is cool! I didnt even know this was a question. Does it take hashed passwords as useradd does? This is very good work, by the way.

Comment: I don't know if I completely agree with the "administrators should..." statement though... Personally, I believe the administrator should probably be putting together his/her own *`adduser`* according to a system-wide policy, but that's just armchair quarterbacking at best.

Comment: @mikeserv, no there are no hashed passwords. There is another program you should know about though - `chpasswd` - this can accept hashed passwords on `stdin`. I will wait til tomorrow before I update that other answer though I think.

Comment: nice post. For me a little too much details. What I miss most is, that `adduser` was originally created for server admin's who frequently needed to create/modify/limit real users like on an email server at university. With `adduser` you can automate the process. This changed a little during the years so nowadays `useradd` can be to difficult for many admins and for them `adduser` has become the tool of choice.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04, `-U`/`--user-group` seem to the default.

Answer (score 5):

One significant difference I ran into (and did not see in an answer here), is the **implications of creating a system user**.

`useradd --system` seems to imply `--shell /bin/bash`, while `adduser --system` implies `--shell /usr/sbin/nologin`, which is what I wanted.

So if I want neither a shell nor a home directory, I could either use **useradd** like this

```
useradd --system --shell /usr/sbin/nologin foo
```

Which leads to e.g. the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
foo:x:994:991::/home/foo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Or use **adduser** like this

```
adduser --system --no-create-home foo
```

Which leads to e.g. the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
foo:x:110:65534::/home/foo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Also, `adduser` does not create a group (user 110 is in group 65534, aka *no group*). The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121072/344229) also mentions risks regarding (G)UID, so I'll definitely stick with **adduser**.

Source: Tested on Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Buster based).

Answer (score 2):

The **adduser** command by default also creates a /home/user directory for system users, which you cannot do with the **useradd** command. useradd only adds home directories for normal users not system users.

Comment: "The adduser command by default also creates a /home/user directory for system users, which you cannot do with the useradd command" Are you sure about that? From <https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/passwd/useradd.8.en.html>: "You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created". I tested on Artix and it works as stated.

Answer (score 1):

The system administrator can do anything with useradd that can be done with adduser. It was stated here that you can't create a /home/user directory for system users with useradd, and you absolutely can, by modifying the files contained in /etc/skel. /etc/skel contains the set of files initially used to populate a new user's home directory.

Comment: It creates the home dir by just passing the `-m` option; there's no need to modify /etc/skel for that.