# Authentication failure for FTP server

Tags: linux, ftp, authentication

I followed [this link](http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/03/05/how-to-setup-vsftpd-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux/) to install ftp server.

And also added ftp user(**ftpuser**) and also added ftp password(**1234567**).

But when I am using this password in any wordpress site or any ftp software such as FileZilla it is showing **530 Login incorrect[image]**

**vsftpd file**

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: you should use `adduser` instead of `useradd` [see this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121071/53092)

Comment: I tried that but no success

Comment: add your vftpd config file, whitout this it will be hard.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem. And that answer is posted by me only.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate - you posted an identical A to this Q and the one that Kiwy mentioned and this solution doesn't solve the problem here or there? Then why did you post either of them?

Comment: The solution which I posted solves my problem and surely it will solve the problem there too. It is one of the possible solution. In my case I found this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit vsftpd.conf (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit CTRL+O & enter to save then CTRL+X to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```