# Add users from dat file

Tags: linux, bash, bash-script, kubuntu

I have a dat file with names. These are the names of users I must add, without groups or passwords. Ofcourse i have to remove all spaces. I have to add them with a bash script. Can anyone help me write the script?

File:

```
Marianne        Earman
Justina Dragaj
Mandy   Mcdonnell
Conrad  Lanfear
Cyril   Behen
Shelley Groden
Rosalind        Krenzke
Davis   Brevard
Winnie  Reich
Trudy   Worlds
Deshawn Inafuku
Claudio Loose
Sal     Pindell
Cristina        Sharper
Tricia  Kruss
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#users.dat | sed "s/\t\t*/ /g"
while read p; do
  #var=$(echo $p | sed "s/\t\t*/ /g")
  var= echo $p | sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g'
  #sudo useradd $var
  sudo useradd $var
 done < users.dat
```

Comment: You are just specifying "write the script". But How? Where is the dat file? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: The file is saved on my computer (/home/tjasa/Documents/). I have to add names in that file as users. Now i heve something like that: 

#!/bin/bash

if [$# -ne 0 ]
then
echo "usage: $0 < file'
exit 1
fi

first=cut -f 1 -d ',' user_list


usern=$first| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'

while read line; do
echo "adding  $usern\n"
done < users.dat

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Make sure you include an example if this "dat" file and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single pipeline - just use `xargs` to run `useradd` for every line in its input:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d; s/[[:space:]]//g' users.dat |
  xargs -I{} echo {}
```

Replace `echo` with `useradd` when you are sure it is doing the right thing.

Note also that if you are writing this for a Debian based system (eg Ubuntu, Linux Mint), you should consider using `adduser` instead of `useradd`. For more details see - [What does adduser do that useradd doesn't?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt)

Comment: Nice one!  But as far as I understand it, you don't need to specify `-d` when also using `-I` since the latter one implies `'\n'` being the input separator.

Comment: @AndreasWiese, that's right, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the output of the `echo` in the `var` variable by appending `$` before executing the command. By that way, `var` will now have the previous command output. Try the below script. It should work fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
var=$(echo $p | sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g')
  echo $var
  #sudo useradd $var
 done < users.dat
```

Comment: You had the output of the `echo` statement assigned correctly to `var` variable, but you have commented it out in your original script.

Comment: This will still attempt an `adduser` (or `echo`) with empty lines. Deleting them with `sed` makes no difference. One thing you could do is check to see if `var` is an empty string (and drop the unnecessary `/^$/d;` part in sed) before doing the last part.