# Bluetoothctl: No default controller available, despite being unblocked

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, bluez

I'm having issues connecting my Logitech K810 Bluetooth keyboard in Debian Jessie with BlueZ version 5.23-1, kernel 3.16.0-4.

The keyboard works fine most of the time but sometimes it doesn't work at all and `bluetoothctl` gives me the error that the controller is unavailable.

When this occurs, hciconfig still recognizes the device and I get this output:

```
# hciconfig hci0 up 
# hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 40:2C:F4:68:02:CA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:21820 acl:1132 sco:0 events:68 errors:0
    TX bytes:1182 acl:11 sco:0 commands:53 errors:0
```

But no devices are shown in the `bluetoothctl` prompt and it gives me this output:

```
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
```

Rebooting or sometimes suspending/resuming fixes the issue: `bluetoothctl` will again recognize both the controller and the keyboard which works again.

Bluetooth is consistently hard and soft unblocked according to `rfkill`.

The relevant output from `lspci -v`, I guess would be this:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        Memory at f0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I didn't have this problem with the same hardware in Debian Wheezy.

What could it be the bluetooth controller to be unavailable at times?

Comment: I have the same problem in OSMC running in Raspberry Pi. Did you find a solution? Share it if you have one, please.

Comment: No, haven't found a solution ...

Comment: I have encountered the same issue with OSMC on  a Raspberry Pi. The keyboard shows up when scanning with hcitool. Bluetoothctl commands result in 'No default controller available'.

Comment: After coming across this question during my investigations several times now: There still seems to be no answer, however, sometimes removing (`modprobe -r btusb`) and adding (`modprobe btusb`) the kernel module helps to get the controller back (so you can avoid doing a full reboot).

Comment: @Dallas see my answer. You just need to run it as sudo and it works fine.

Comment: @MajorBriggs please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I have been struggling with the same problem for months now, and none of the above solutions worked for me.

After a lot of research I found this solution on an old forum that worked for me

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271459

```
rmmod btusb
rmmod btintel

modprobe btintel
modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please edit your post to add a link to the "old forum" where you found this solution.

Comment: tysm! I was going nuts with this and this solved it.

Comment: Using ubuntu 22.04.3,  I had this issue after a power cut off, tried everything but only this worked for me too!

Comment: I had the same issue, this solution worked. I have the Intel AX200, using Debian (6.1.0-10-amd64). My `dmesg -k | grep -i bluetooth` reported this error: `Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is simply to run `bluetoothctl` with `sudo`.

Thus, `sudo bluetoothctl`. Then every command works fine `power on`, `agent on` etc. with no errors.

Confirmed working on Raspian Stretch.

Answer (score 4):

This is a long-standing issue, but it doesn't affect all distributions equally. My experience with it is limited to the Debian derivative for Raspberry Pi - Raspberry Pi OS (née Raspbian). In particular, the "Lite" version of the RPiOS distro is afflicted, but the "Full" version is not.

The issue seems to be that the default user (and all users I suspect) are not included in the secondary group named `bluetooth` in the "Lite" version of RaspOS as they are in the "Full" version.

A ***patch*** for that is easy enough: *add the user to the `bluetooth` group*

```bsh
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

Or perhaps this as @Pablo has suggested below:

```
$ sudo adduser $USER bluetooth
```

Once this is done (and after a `reboot` IIRC), `bluetoothctl` becomes effective, and the Controller becomes responsive. `sudo` was not required afterwards.

While this patch is easy, a permanent solution would be far better - this is very confusing, and has been so for at least 7-8 years. I'd submit a bug report, but in my experience with Debian and Raspbian, that's a further waste of time.

Comment: I wonder why nobody seems to use `sudo adduser $USER bluetooth`, it's much more easy to remember end [more user friendly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121072/209677)

Answer (score 0):

Is kernel update an option?

Have you tried the latest linux-firmware package?

Also you can try the suggestions in secion "About iwldvm support and known issues" in here https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

I have Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 with dual boot enabled (Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10).
After trying all the above solution.

- Just boot into Windows. (Bluetooth is also not working in Windows)
- Update the Bluetooth drivers from there.
- Restarted into Windows. (Bluetooth is now working)
- Reboot back into Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

First enable bluetooth manually with the GUI. this is how it worked for me.
i know this post is old, but it worked for me. Just search in your main menu for "bluetooth"
(On my current mint 18 sarah it is like that)

You can then come back and try the commands with "power off"

Comment: What GUI? What exact steps? How would powering it off help establish a connection?

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading from Debian Buster to Bullseye: `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` then open bluetoothctl in a terminal, enable bluettooth via the top bar menu and see the "new controller" message appear in bluetoothctl.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try `systemctl start hciuart`

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! I suggest to explain, what you are doing and why.