# Bluetooth: No default controller available

Tags: bluetooth, bodhi

I am using Bodhi 6.0.
This is what I have

```
(base) $ sudo hciconfig -a

(base) $ systemctl status bluetooth.service
. bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

abr 24 19:09:06 Orion systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
abr 24 19:11:45 Orion systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.

(base) $ sudo modprobe btusb
[sudo] password for user1:

(base) $ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service

(base) $ systemctl status bluetooth.service
. bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-24 19:13:26 -03; 2s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1974 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8967)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1974 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

abr 24 19:13:26 Orion systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
abr 24 19:13:26 Orion bluetoothd[1974]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
abr 24 19:13:26 Orion systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
abr 24 19:13:26 Orion bluetoothd[1974]: Starting SDP server
abr 24 19:13:26 Orion bluetoothd[1974]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20

(base) $ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available

(base) $ lspci -knn | grep -i -A 4 network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8212]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)

(base) $ dmesg | grep -e rtl8192ce -e btusb
[   16.059276] rtl8192ce: Chip Version ID: B_CUT_88C
[   16.077515] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
[   16.269831] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[  299.282444] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb

(base) $ lsmod | grep -e rtl8192ce -e btusb
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
bluetooth             651264  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
rtl8192ce              61440  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        65536  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                94208  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
mac80211             1028096  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce

(base) $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

(base) $ uname -a
Linux Orion 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Notes:

1. I have to insert manually btusb, and then restart (I could automate this at startup).

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267837 describes a similar problem, but not the same (rfkill list all shows hci0: Bluetooth as unblocked).
Post https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1987755#p1987755 fixed it with a patch for 5.13.10.
Some say with 5.14.7 this was fixed, some still see the issue even with 5.14.10.

Related:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279646/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available
2. [Bluetoothctl: No default controller available, despite being unblocked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169931/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available-despite-being-unblocked)
3. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267837
4. https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=4375