# Why login with user created with useradd command in Debian has no enviroment set?

Tags: debian, users, environment-variables

I started to learn linux and I came a cross problem I would like to ask. After I use useradd command in debian, I get new user with home directory. I check that directories from /etc/skel are copied and everything seems fine. But when I log to user with su - user I get only $ sign and I see that PS1 variable is not set, colours and other things. User created with adduser doesn't have this problem and If I check difference between .bashrc and .profile files for both users, there are the same. So why is this happening?

Comment: Are you *certain* that you used the hyphen in the `su - user` ?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121071/117549

Comment: Which login *shell* was assigned to the user?

Answer (score 6):

When you use `useradd` you have to specify all sorts of stuff - default shell, home directory, etc.  If you aren't seeing a normal bash prompt, I would assume that you didn't specify `/bin/bash` as the user's shell and it defaulted to `/bin/sh` or similar.

To be honest, `useradd` is great for when you are adding users programmatically via a script.  Not so great for one-off adding a single user.

Much better to instead use `adduser newusername` ....

Comment: `adduser` is good for scripted user creation too - just remember to use `--disabled-password` so it doesn't prompt for a password.  You can set the password later with `echo user:pass | chpasswd`.

Comment: Do you know of other things than the shell that must be set with `useradd`, or do you have a reference explaining it? `adduser` prompts user questions that aren't raised during the part of the installation where the 'main' user gets created. I'd like to create a user similar to those 'main' users.