# how to install "adduser" on arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

On Ubuntu, there is a useful package called `adduser`.

But on Arch Linux, I searched it by `pacman -Ss adduser`, and got nothing.

I'm not sure is it in `extra repository` or `user repository`, or actually it's not in the arch linux ecosystem?

Is there another way to search it on Arch Linux except installing it directly from downloaded source code?

Answer (score 12):

There is no `adduser` command in Arch Linux.

As [the wiki makes clear](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#User_management), Arch uses `useradd`. And there is no need to install anything, as it is packaged as part of the `[core]` repository:

```
pacman -Fs useradd
  core/shadow 4.5-4
```

In general, it is a good idea to abandon your reliance on how Ubuntu does things when you move to Arch. Arch provides all of the tools that you require to competently administer your system, and a package manager that suports you identifying which packages provide these tools.

And a wiki that meticulously documents them.

See this question for the differences between the two:
[What does adduser do that useradd doesn't?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt)

Answer (score 4):

To install the [`adduser`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/adduser/) command, use:

```
pacman -S yaourt
yaourt -S adduser
```

Note that `yaourt` is deprecated. You may now add users using `adduser`.

A reasonably equivalent command is:

```
useradd -m -G groupname -s bash username
```

When you have some spare time, [study the documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#User_management).

Comment: needs to use /bin/bash in useradd otherwise I got "useradd: invalid shell 'bash'"